# Getting and Displaying Battery info on Android Wear Watchface

Tags: wear-os, batterylevel

I am using the Sample Watchface code from below
 https://github.com/googlecodelabs/watchface

I am trying to add the battery level info to watchface but I get this error.

> 12-20 11:39:15.042 2914-2914/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.android.wearable.watchface, PID: 2914
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   com.example.android.wearable.watchface.watchface.DigitalWatchFaceService:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Intent
>   android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,
>   android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3389)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.Intent
>   android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,
>   android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference
>   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:603)
>   at
>   com.example.android.wearable.watchface.watchface.DigitalWatchFaceService.(DigitalWatchFaceService.java:81)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3386)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)  12-20
>   11:39:15.082 2914-2914/com.example.android.wearable.watchface
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2914 SIG: 9

This is the bit of code in "DigitalWatchFaceService.java" that causes the error

```
// Battery code
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Comment: Formatted the exception message

Comment: Why are you trying to register a null `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked using this:

public String getBatteryLevel() {
    Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

```
// Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
if(level == -1 || scale == -1) {
    return "error";
}


float batteryLevelWithDecimals = ((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f;
String battery = String.format("%.0f", batteryLevelWithDecimals);
return battery ;
```

}

Then you can call the battery level string like this:

```
        canvas.drawText(
                String.valueOf(getBatteryLevel()),
                mXOffset, mYOffset + mLineHeight * 3, mDatePaint);
```